# Need help understanding binary relations...

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Let $R$ be a relation on a set $A$. Is $R$ a partial order?

$A = \{0,1,2,3\}$

$R = \{(0,0), (1,1), (2,0), (2,2), (2,3), (3,2), (3,3)\}$

I know that it's reflexive, not anti-symmetric, and not transitive. I have the answer.

Can someone explain to me why it is not transitive?

Comment: Is $R$ correctly written? With the pairs $(2,3)$ and $(3,2)$ in, it is definitely *not* ant-symmetric.

Comment: Please note the simple $\LaTeX$ formatting I did to the text of your question.

Comment: Yes, R is correctly written. I have taken it from the lecture slides. I did mention that it is not antisymmetric.

Comment: Ah, ok, but then it's not a partial order.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Can you tell me why it is not transitive? It looks transitive to me.

Comment: Did you try to draw it on paper (you know, with relations written as arrows going from a point to another) ? If you did, then you should see immediately which arrow is missing.

Answer (score 2):

It's not transitive because $3$ relates to $2$, $2$ relates to $0$, but $3$ does not relate to $0$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Why did I not see that...